# how to solve error break statement is not within loop or switch

Tags: c, loops, break

Hi I was study for computer and we got this assignment to do break statement in c
this is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float num, sum=0;
    int i,n;
    
    printf("Maximum no. of inputs\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    for(i=1; i<=n; ++i);
    {
        printf("Enter number %d: ", i);
        scanf("%f", &num);
        
        if(num<0.0)
         break;         //for loop breaks if num < 0.0
         
    sum = sum + sum;
    }
    
    printf("Total addition: %.2f ", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

I already copy like my lecture instruct but I got the error break statement is not within loop
or switch. I don't know were wrong so I hope you can tell the error and some explain for me thank you

Comment: Typo: as the answers point out, there is a stray semicolon at the end of `for(i=1; i<=n; ++i);` that needs to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

You have a stray `;` after your `for` loop:

```
//     here  ------v
for(i=1; i<=n; ++i);
{
```

This means you actually have a `for` loop with an empty body followed by a standalone block statement, so the `break` is not inside of a loop.

Get rid of the extra `;` so that the block statement is the body of the loop.

```
for(i=1; i<=n; ++i)
{
```

Comment: Thanks for helping and point the mistake

Comment: @Zerefslayer Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

On the line with `for(i=1; i<=n; ++i);` you have an added semicolon that prevents the contents of the for loop from being executed. The corrected code would be as follows:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float num, sum=0;
    int i,n;
    
    printf("Maximum no. of inputs\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    for(i=1; i<=n; ++i)
    {
        printf("Enter number %d: ", i);
        scanf("%f", &num);
        
        if(num<0.0)
         break;         //for loop breaks if num < 0.0
         
    sum = sum + sum;
    }
    
    printf("Total addition: %.2f ", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing the mistake I will remember to not make the same mistake